# Did the Juno mission locate Jupiter at the same precision as Saturn (4 km)?

Tags: jupiter, ephemeris, vlbi

Juno's low perijove should be great for measuring Jupiter's gravitational effect on Juno's orbit. Cassini together with [VLBI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very-long-baseline_interferometry) has measured Saturn's location to within 4 km.

<s>Will</s> Was Juno <s>be</s> able to be measured by VLBI to determine Jupiter's location and orbit at a similar precision? At a precision useful for mapping the Solar System outside of the Kuiper Belt?

Comment: Without doing the leg work to really find an answer, I'm going to go with: I doubt it. Cassini has been orbiting Saturn for 12 years now. That's a lot of good data. Juno will only last ~1.5 years and won't have any orbital maneuvers. That's likely not enough to get precise measurements of Jupiter's position, and frankly isn't a science goal of the Juno mission.